# JDBC mySQL DML Error

Tags: mysql, dml

I am trying display all the relevant information for jobs done to a customer using a JOIN TABLE QUERY.

Here is my code...

```
SELECT Bill.BillID, Duty.TaskTime 
FROM Invoice 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Duty.JobID = Bill.JobID
WHERE Job.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
```

I keep getting this error...
'#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.JobID WHERE Job.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID' at line 3'

Comment: I think you need to spend sometime reading how to write SQL Joins. Your query doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: Doesn't seem like you have any aliases declared.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to access tables that you haven't told the query about in both your `WHERE` and `SELECT` clauses.  When you say `Bill.BillID` in your `SELECT` clause, you're saying that you want the Field `BillID` from the table called `Bill`.

The rule your syntax is breaking is that you can't use a table name in the `SELECT` or `WHERE` clauses, unless you've mentioned it in the `FROM` clause (or a `JOIN`).

So now, let's look at your query.

```
SELECT Bill.BillID, Duty.TaskTime 
FROM Invoice 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Duty.JobID = Bill.JobID
WHERE Job.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
```

This means that you want to pick fields from the tables named `Bill` and `Duty`, and filter the results based on fields from the `Job` and `Customer` tables.  However, you've only mentioned one table by name in the `FROM` clause (`Invoice`).  You've *almost* joined the `Duty` table, but you're joining it to a place in a table you haven't mentioned yet (`Bill`).  I'm going to *guess* that you intend to use `Bill` as an *alias* for `Invoice`.  That would mean that what you really want is more like:

```
// Still incorrect
SELECT Bill.BillID, Duty.TaskTime 
FROM Invoice AS Bill
LEFT OUTER JOIN Duty ON Duty.JobID = Bill.JobID
WHERE Job.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID
```

But we still haven't mentioned either the `Job` or `Customer` tables that are referenced in the `WHERE` clause.  In order to use them, you need to `JOIN` those tables as well.  We'd need to know more about your schema to figure out how to do that, but I can tell you that you'll need at *least* two more `JOIN` clauses.  Assuming that you have a `CustomerID` field on the `Invoice` table, we probably want to join like this.

```
// speculative
SELECT Bill.BillID, Duty.TaskTime
FROM Invoice AS Bill
LEFT OUTER JOIN Duty ON Duty.JobID = Bill.JobID
JOIN Customer ON Customer.CustomerID = Bill.CustomerID
JOIN Job ON // Well, something...We don't know.
```

I *strongly* recommend you spend some time reading and studying the excellent [Wikipedia entry on SQL JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).  Good luck~

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is how you point your tables, maybe:

FROM Invoice as Bill LEFT OUTER JOIN NameTable2 as Duty ON Dury.JobID=Bill.JobID

Comment: Now I am getting an error for the 'WHERE Job.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID'. I don't know what to do

Comment: ok, as you're now so once was I :)  look: when you refer a column in sql, we use the following structure:  DataBase.Owner.TableOrAlias.column, so you wrote WHERE Job.CustomerID, the mistake is you didn´t refer the Job tables in the FROM clause. The last code above us from LanMcLaird is close what you need, sorry,we can't guess how is your database in order to help you